# Recycler View Fetching Data When Swiping from Bottom

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i want to fetch data when the user touches the recycler and scrolls down when the recycler is already at the bottom end (Like swiping from bottom but when the recycler cant scroll any more).  Any ideas?

Thank you

```
 @Override public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)     
 {
     super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
     StaggeredGridLayoutManager manager =
    (StaggeredGridLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();

       int visibleItemCount = manager.getChildCount();
       int totalItemCount = manager.getItemCount();
       int[] firstVisibleItems = manager.findFirstVisibleItemPositions(null);
       if (firstVisibleItems != null && firstVisibleItems.length > 0) {

        }

       if (visibleItemCount + pastVisibleItems >= totalItemCount) {

     } 

 }
```

Comment: You have asked same question 15 minutes ago m i right? https://stackoverflow.com/q/51478637/7666442

Comment: what is the outcome of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override 
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)     
{
   super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
   StaggeredGridLayoutManager manager = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();

   if(manager.findLastVisibleItemPosition() == manager.getItemCount()-1) 
   {
        // We have reached the end of the recycler view.
   }
}
```

Comment: This will fetch data when the last element becomes visible not when you reach the bottom

Answer (score -1):

Check this open source library for example:
https://github.com/Malinskiy/SuperRecyclerView

It has setupMoreLoading method which attach listener and call method when `X` element left to be scrolled.

This is how it's done there:

```
     ...
     mInternalOnScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            processOnMore();

            if (mExternalOnScrollListener != null)
                mExternalOnScrollListener.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if (mSwipeDismissScrollListener != null)
                mSwipeDismissScrollListener.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            if (mExternalOnScrollListener != null)
                mExternalOnScrollListener.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            if (mSwipeDismissScrollListener != null)
                mSwipeDismissScrollListener.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }
    };
    mRecycler.addOnScrollListener(mInternalOnScrollListener);
    ....

private void processOnMore() {
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = mRecycler.getLayoutManager();
    int lastVisibleItemPosition = getLastVisibleItemPosition(layoutManager);
    int visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
    int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();

    if (((totalItemCount - lastVisibleItemPosition) <= ITEM_LEFT_TO_LOAD_MORE ||
         (totalItemCount - lastVisibleItemPosition) == 0 && totalItemCount > visibleItemCount)
        && !isLoadingMore) {

        isLoadingMore = true;
        if (mOnMoreListener != null) {
            mMoreProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mOnMoreListener.onMoreAsked(mRecycler.getAdapter().getItemCount(), ITEM_LEFT_TO_LOAD_MORE, lastVisibleItemPosition);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir, While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. have a look **[answer]**

Comment: I want on gesture Swipe from Bottom to load more items.